# nonces in custom oop plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

How to use the `check_admin_referer` method with oop?
If I use as it follows the function can not be called:

```
class MyClass{
    function __construct(){ 

        if( isset($_POST['my_nonce_field']) && check_admin_referer('my_nonce_action', 'my_nonce_field')){               
            $this->update_item();
        }

    }
}
```

$test = new MyClass();

The above leads to the following error message:

```
Call to undefined function check_admin_referer()
```

Comment: Please post more context. How are you attempting to use this block of code? How do you instantiate the object?

Comment: I should add that I use `check_admin_referer` in plugins and in Object context. I think the problem is how you using it. In the constructor `var_dump(function_exists('check_admin_referer'));` does return false, at least in the simple testing I've done. I haven't worked out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`check_admin_referer` is a [pluggable function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) which means it is defined after plugins are loaded so call your constructor or instantiate the object after or using `plugins_loaded` action hook.

ex:

```
class MyClass{
    function __construct(){ 
        if( isset($_POST['my_nonce_field']) && check_admin_referer('my_nonce_action', 'my_nonce_field'))
            $this->update_item();
    }
}

add_action('plugins_loaded','newobj');
function newobj(){
    $myclass = new MyClass;
}
```

Comment: +1. Alternative: hook an additional method to `'plugins_loaded'` (or any subsequent action) from within the constructor.

Comment: yep that would do the same thing.